# How do I access a variable inside a class method from outside it?

Tags: python, class, variables, methods

Here's my code throwing out AttributeError. How can I access the `abc` variable and print it out?

For some reason I don't want the `foo` class to return `"ABC"`. Yes, I know I can do it, but I'm searching for a different solution. Thanks for help.

```
class John:   
    def foo(self):
        abc = "ABC"

a = John()
print(a.foo.abc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the variable inside the class `John` as an attribute of the class. Like so:

```
class John:
    def __init__(self):  # You have to have this initialization method, which is called when you do 'John()'
        self.foo()
    def foo(self):
        self.abc = "ABC"  # Note the use of 'self.'

a = John()
print(a.abc)  # abc is an attribute of 'John', no need to pass through 'foo'
```

**EDIT**

`__init__()` executes when you create an instance of the class, `a = John()`. Inside the `__init__()` you can do anything you would do in a function of the class. You can create attributes in the spot (using `self.` before the attribute name) or call either functions or class methods (in this case, we called the `foo` mehtod, **with self.**). Therefore, in this line:

```
a = John()
```

You are creating an instance of the class `John`, assigning it to `a`, and executing `John.__init__()`, which executes `John.foo()`, which creates the attribute `John.abc`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'John' object has no attribute 'abc'

Comment: Added a brief explanation. You can, as @offeltoffel said, create the attribute right there on the __init__ methdo, instead of calling a function which does nothing but that.

Comment: If it works, please consider marking the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an `__init__` function.

```
class John:   
    def __init__(self):
        self.abc = "ABC"

a = John()
print(a.abc)
```

The **init** function is called as soon as you create a new instance of that class. So as soon as the John-class gets a new instance ("a"), it has the variable "abs" attached to it.

Within your class you can address the `abc` variable with `self.abc`, from outside you replace `self` by the name of your instance.